# Height = 100%, when zoom, height not 100%, but scrollable. how?

Tags: web, height, scrollable

maybe a tricky one.. or maybe very easy!

I'm creating a website that is relatively equal in size on every device, mobile or desktop.
I'm using the 
    html { height=100%; } 
for it.

The problem is: When zoom=100%, the site looks nice, but when you zoom in on desktop, (except with safari), the site stays at height=100%.

I want to have when the website is zoomed, the website gets scrollable, which results in a smoother look, because not everything is narrow on eachother, but rather spread, same as when the website is on zoom=100%.

The website currently is at the state of:
     http://prototyping.iscs.nl/

Have a look, zoom in and you see my problem.

I hope someone has a clue how to fix this!

Maybe something as making it one whole column, when zoom is 'more than' 100%, make it scrollable ?

Thanks in advance!